# Creating a UITableView class and assign to storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, datasource

Is it possible to create a class UITableview and assign to UITableview in storyboard? I have this example but the delegate methods don't call. and the table appears empty.

In the class Table.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Table : UITableView <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

In the class Table.m:

```
@implementation Table{

    NSArray *data;
}

-(instancetype)init{

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate= self;
        self.dataSource = self;
        data = @[@"bmw",@"mercedes",@"audi"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [data count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

And finally, in my ViewController.m it's here I need to be implemented.
I have this code:

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "Table.h"

    @interface ViewController ()
    @end

    @implementation ViewController 

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        Table *mainTable = [Table new];
        self.table = mainTable;
    }
    @end
```

Comment: I have to assume that `ViewController` is a subclass of `UITableViewController`. How is your Storyboard setup? Have you overridden the class of the "dropped-in" controller (which class/component did you use there)?

Comment: Yes, ViewController is a subclass of UITableViewController, And In my storyboard, I have a UITableview assigned to class Table. 

I try to do customize a TableView so it can be reused anywhere.

Comment: as @GeneCode mentioned - normally you would have a "controller" that implements the table source/delegates as controller provides the data to it's view - table. In Storyboard you then need to have a UIViewController component where you would override the class to your `ViewController`

Answer (score 0):

how to create Sublasss for tableView

```
   // MyTableView.h

// This overrides the UITableViewDataSource with your own so you can add any methods   you would like.
    @protocol MyTableViewDataSource <UITableViewDataSource>

    @required
    // This is where you put methods that are required for your custom table to work (optional)
    - (int)myRequiredMethod;

    @optional
    // This is where you put methods that are optional, like settings (optional)

    @end

    // This overrides the UITableViewDelegate with your own so you can add any methods you would like.
    @protocol MyTableViewDelegate <UITableViewDelegate>

    @required
    // This is where you put methods that are required for your custom table to work (optional)

    @optional
    // This is where you put methods that are optional, like settings (optional)

    @end

    // Make sure you add UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource implementations.
    @interface MyTableView : UITableView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

        // Your customer datasource and delegate.
        id <MyTableViewDataSource> myDataSource;
        id <MyTableViewDelegate> myDelegate;
    }

    @end


        //MyTableView.m



        #import "MyTableView.h"

        @implementation MyTableView

        - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
        {
            self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
            if (self) {
                // Initialization code

                // This is how you can use your custom method.
                int i = [myDataSource myRequiredMethod];
            }
            return self;
        }

        - (void)awakeFromNib {
            // This assigns the delegate and datasource you assigned to File's Owner in your xib to your custom methods
            myDataSource = (id<MyTableViewDataSource>)self.dataSource;
            myDelegate = (id<MyTableViewDelegate>)self.delegate;
            self.delegate = self;
            self.dataSource = self;
        }

        // This is an example of how to override an existing UITableView method.
        - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

            // This calls the method implemented in your ViewController. See Below.
            NSInteger rows = [myDataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];

            return rows;
        }

        @end

        //MyViewController.h







    #import "MyTableView.h"

        // Use MyTableViewDataSource and MyTableViewDelegate instead of UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate
        @interface MyViewController : UIViewController <MyTableViewDataSource, MyTableViewDelegate> {

        @end


       // MyViewController.m




     #import "MyViewController.h"

        @interface MyViewController ()

        @end

        @implementation MyViewController

        - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
        {
            self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
            if (self) {
                // Custom initialization
            }
            return self;
        }

        - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];
        }

        // This method will be overridden by myTableViewDataSource
        - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
            return 1;
        }

        - (int)myRequiredMethod {
            return 2;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the concept here. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish - subclass a TableView (ie customize a TableView so it can be reused anywhere), or creating your own TableViewController. Delegates are to be implemented on Controllers and not on the object itself. So your self.delegate=self is wrong and does not make sense.

Comment: As you said I try to do customize a TableView so it can be reused anywhere. If you have a tip I will very appreciate.